Should we merge the "Rijndael" tag with the "AES" tag?
We currently have the tags rijndael (59 questions tagged) and aes (1135 questions tagged).
Since all Rijndael questions tend to boil down to being about AES, it could make sense to make rijndael a synonym of aes.
Should we merge the Rijndael tag with the AES tag, making it a synonym of the later? Is there any reason not to do so?
EDIT
For your convenience, I added YES/NO answers for easier voting. Yet, that doesn't mean those are the only valid answers. Please feel more than welcome to add your own answer anytime.

I see two potential points where a distinct tag could make sense: History of the cipher (especially pre-AES) and features / properties / whatever that aren't included in the AES standard but were specified for Rijndael (such as 256-bit blocks for example). But then I haven't checked (yet) whether such questions have been tagged aes or rijndael, whether we have such questions at all and for what the rijndael tag is used in general.

This question for example asks about pro / contra for the different block sizes, which is a property of Rijndael and not AES.

The only problem I see is indeed if anybody is looking for Rijndael specific things like block sizes or key sizes. You'll never find your issue by going through 1135 + 59 questions in that case. You could of course add another search term such as block size, but that's sub-optimal at best. My first idea was to go for it and merge them, but I'm not so sure anymore.

@MaartenBodewes Good pointer. Thanks for the feedback! To be honest, I also stumbled over the "could be merged, but they're a tick different nevertheless" issue. Anyway... just wished you had posted it as an answer so I could've upvoted and/or accepted something.

@SEJPM Thanks for your feedback too. And same "wished you had posted it as an answer" goes out to you too.  ;)

No
rijndael was what later became aes, but there are specific differences between both. Those differences surely justify both tags to exists next to each other. If only, as it might help users find answers to Rijndael-specific questions easier. Making one a synonym of the other would be rather non-constructive from that perspective.

Yes
Making rijndael a synonym of aes makes sense as there's not much difference which would justify keeping the two tags seperate.
